# What do "Centro" and "Título" mean when referring to a "Máster" degree in a submission form?

Tags: traducción

I am filling an application form, which is in Spanish. I am using Google Translate to fill the form but it is giving unhelpful translations for some phrases. Could someone please help me by translating these phrases to English? What should I write in these two fields in the form ? Thanks in advance.

1. Centro del Máster
2. Título del Máster

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With *Centro* they are referring to the **place** (school/college) where you studied this *Máster*, e.g. School of Blablabla, University of Thisandthat, etc.

With *Título* they are referring to the Degree itself, e.g. "Máster in economics" or "Máster in Computer Science" or the like.

Answer (score 2):

"Máster" is "master's degree" so, "Centro del Máster" is where you get the master and "Título el Máster" is you master, what's your master degree.